# How to handle special characters (such as "&") in Convert Query Params to XML of datapower

Tags: ibm-datapower

I am new to datapower, so I am sorry its silly question.

I have create one flow in datapower whose request and response type is Non-XML.
when I try to post an XML to my flow I am getting following error.

`Convert HTTP produced invalid XML: mismatched tag, expected employed_by at offset`

here is the sample request XML :-

```
...
<emp_status type="employed" />
<employed_by>abc &amp; company</employed_by>
<work_phone_no>XXXXX</work_phone_no>
<years_employed>10</years_employed>
<months_employed>10</months_employed> 
...
```

but If I remove `&amp;` from the request XML then my flow works fine.

Comment: why are you setting request type to Non-XML when you intend to pass XML into it?

Comment: As per the requirement the request can we xml or non-xml so we set it in such way ...

Comment: and at what place does the "XML production" take place that throws the "mismatched tag" error?

Comment: While performing "Convert Query Params to XML", it didn't able to understand special char (&) due to which it throw an error saying mismatch tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is query string then &-sign is `%26` and not `&amp;`!

If it is non-xml you are going for I'd recommend using GatewayScript instead for all parsing!